# Como apagar branches do git que não existem no remoto

Tags: git, branch

No meu projeto atual, criei localmente vários branches para testes locais - todos à partir da master. Agora, tenho mais de 20 branches locais que não existem no servidor.

Eu queria fazer uma faxina aqui, e apagar todos os branches locais que não existem remotamente (quer por já terem sido deletadas remotamente, ou por nunca terem existido lá). Eu não tava querendo deletar um por um, na mão, mas ainda não achei alternativa...

O que me recomendam? Alguém sabe como fazer com um comando só? Um script também é aceitável - eu uso Windows, mas não quero limitar respostas para outros sistemas operacionais, caso alguém sugira um script ou coisa do tipo...

Comment: Acho que seria bom limitar para o seu sistema operacional, senão vai chover respostas que nem vão ser úteis para você.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No Windows Power Shell, [conforme resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49047069/10707951):

```
git checkout master; git remote update origin --prune; git branch -vv | Select-String -Pattern ": gone]" | % { $_.toString().Trim().Split(" ")[0]} | % {git branch -d $_}
```

Answer (score 5):

O comando abaixo deleta todas branches deletadas ou que nunca existiram no remoto:

```
git fetch -p && for branch in `git branch -vv | grep ': gone]' | awk '{print $1}'`; do git branch -D $branch; done
```

Comment: grep - usado nessa linha - é comando do Linux. Aceitei a outra resposta pois no momento estou usando Windows e aquela funcionou. Mas essa aqui é muito útil também para quem usa Linux

Comment: se tiver no windows usando git bash esse comando funciona também!

Comment: Verdade, Eduardo... bom ponto